# Unity: Positioning an element on canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to move an image down through canvas so that its central point would be where is now its top edge. It makes some 50 points, but if I decrease y by 50, it moves to different part of the screen on devices with different screen size. I guess, it's because my main canvas is set to scale with the screen size. So I suppose I need to manually divide the number 50 by my screen height and then code to multiply by Screen.height? Isn't there a more convenient way to move UI objects?

Allow me a second question: Do you think it is even wise to make a game purely on canvas? My game is simple 2D, only slightly animated and contains many layout elements, so I decided to go for it, but I have hard time to grasp the UI position rules.

Comment: I think you will have an easier time using sprites instead of Canvas to make a game.  Just my opinion though. I find moving RectTransforms manually with code has outcomes that are difficult to predict since there are more variables that affect the result.

Answer (score 1):

you may have the problem of the anchoring.

Unity UI totally depends on the Anchoring, if you have got right anchoring there is no issue.
For example. if you anchored something at the Center than changing left and right value moves them according to the center anchor.

for clear visualization, you can paste a screenshot of the behavior.

Comment: I am talking about a code like 'rectTransform.position = new Vector2(oldPosition.x, oldPosition.y - 50)'. I am saying that it moves the element by a different screen portion, depending on the actual screen size.
Are you telling me that it doesn't?